# How to start the Community Edition in Neo4j Desktop?

Tags: neo4j

I would like to use Neo4j to learn how graph databases work and make some experiences with my own datasets. According to that and since Neo4j claims to be open source I've downloaded the Windows Neo4j Desktop version, but every project and database initialized shows the "Enterprise" attribute which means that I just initialized the Enterprise edition.

Any idea how to setup a project and a database based on the community edition?

Comment: why do you need the community version when you have the enterprise version for free?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. If you dont setup path variables you have enter the bin directory via cmd and type "neo4j.bat install-service" and then neo4j.bat to start the database-server. The officiall installation instructions should have those details.

Answer (score 0):

just open a commandline in the bin folder. There you execute the command "neo4j.bat console" which creates a local server, that you then reach via localhost:7474.

Answer (score -2):

The [neo4j Download Center](https://neo4j.com/download-center/) allows you to choose between downloading the Enterprise Edition, the Community Edition, and the Desktop.

Comment: I think the OP's goal was to download Desktop and configure it to launch instances of the Community Edition servers. To have the convenient UI while running CE servers.